# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader' when starting Anaconda Powershell Prompt

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

When I open the Anaconda 3 Powershell Prompt it is giving this on startup (see below). Some similar problems have received various answers which I find confusing to implement, could someone offer a step-by-step solution to this? (I believe it has something to do with matplotlib.) Thanks!

> Error processing line 1 of
>   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-3.1.1-py3.7-nspkg.pth:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
>         exec(line)
>       File "", line 1, in 
>       File "", line 580, in module_from_spec   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
>   'loader'
>
> Remainder of file ignored

Answer (score 0):

There are several similar bug reports on Anaconda's Github page. For example [1672](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1672). The recommendation is not to use PowerShell as it's not fully supported:

> @cbcoutinho it looks like you are using powershell. Our activate scripts don't currently support that, and without them, you really shouldn't trust that you have correct environment variables set.
>
> You should stick to using the "Anaconda Prompt" on windows. Adding powershell support is soemthing we'd like to do, but we don't have a definite timeline for it.

Comment: Even with Anaconda Prompt I am still getting this: Error processing line 1 of C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-3.1.1-py3.7-nspkg.pth: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage exec(line) File "<string>", line 1, in <module> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 580, in module_from_spec AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader' Remainder of file ignored –

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, I am still getting this when I use the Anaconda prompt:

```
Error processing line 1 of C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-3.1.1-py3.7-nspkg.pth: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage exec(line) File "<string>", line 1, in <module> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 580, in module_from_spec AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader' Remainder of file ignored –
```